# Setting the background image of iPhone from an app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was wondering if it was possible to set the IPhone's background image from an App. I have an image which is a UIImageView. Like when the phone is locked theres the "wallpaper background image." Is there a way to make a button which can set the wallpaper of the phone as my UIImageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted my google search to "wallpaper" terminology and I found this:

`http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/36103-can-sdk-app-change-wallpaper-iphone.html`

It appears this is only possible on a jailbroken iphone.

Answer (score 1):

In your background view (you might have to drag an IBOutlet to it) say like:

```
imageView.bounds = view.bounds;
imageView.hidden = YES;
[view addSubview:imageView];
```

Then when your button is pressed (possibly an IBAction) do this to turn the background on and off.

```
if (imageView.hidden){
   imageView.hidden = NO;
}else{
   imageView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I mean like the Wallpaper on the iphone, like when the phone is locked and you see a custom wallpaper, I can adjust the question to reflect this

Comment: Oh my bad. Not possible without a jailbreak.